# undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Friend i found nil method error for capitalize. but i don't know why. please help me out thanks

```
    <% if current_user %>  
      Hi <%=current_user.name.split(' ').first.capitalize %>, please.</p>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: What is the name attribute of the `current_user`?

Comment: first_name last_name and others.

Answer (score 3):

The particular user that is currently logged in has a "blank" name.

```
current_user.name #=> ""
current_user.name.split #=> []
current_user.name.split.first #=> nil
current_user.name.split.first.capitalize #=> Error
```

As a quick fix, change your code to this:

```
current_user.name.split.first.to_s.capitalize
```

The name will still appear as blank though.

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid such long chaining.
What I can advice, go to you current_user class definition and add the method:

```
def first_name
  name.split(' ').first
end
```

Getting back to you template you can make use of try() method

```
<%=current_user.first_name.try(:capitalize) %>
```

The next step could be moving first_name() method from current_user into some wrapper class. Read more about presenters to achieve that.